# consider the table of indices of 13 to the base 2 are

Tags: number-theory

consider the table of indices of 13 to the base 2 are

[image]

**I'm stuck on i , ii) , need help please**

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to understand the table. The second column says that $2^1\equiv2$, the third column says that $2^4\equiv3$, etc. So all you need to do is scan the list to see where a column has the same number twice, namely $10$.

For the second question, since $9\equiv2^8$ and $11\equiv2^7$, your equation to solve is $2^7x^{71}\equiv2^8\pmod{13}$, so you want $x^{71}\equiv2$, but you know, I hope, that $x^{12}\equiv1$, so you’re solving $x^{-1}\equiv2$, so $x$ must be the thing with index congruent to $-1\pmod{12}$, namely $7$. You check, of course, that $2\cdot7\equiv1\pmod{13}$.

p.s. Why oh why is the author using the notation “ind”? I would have called it $\log_2$, since the index-sub-$2$ of $a$ is the exponent to which $2$ must be raised to get $a$.

Comment: $\text{ind}_g$, or plain $\text{ind}$ when $g$ is understood, is the traditional old-style notation.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thanks. Just shows how parochial and provincial my upbringing has been.